# How to match and divide

Tags: r, data.table

Given the following data tables:

```
df1 <- data.table(V1=c("A","C","D","B"),V2=c(0,2,0,2),V3=c(2,0,2,0))
df2 <- data.table(V1=c("A","B","C","D"),V2=c(4,2,4,2))
df1
df2
> df1
   V1 V2 V3
1:  A  0  2
2:  C  2  0
3:  D  0  2
4:  B  2  0
> df2
   V1 V2
1:  A  4
2:  B  2
3:  C  4
4:  D  2
```

I seek the following: for every numerical value of df1, divide this value for the corresponding value from df2, using V1 as a key. The resulting data table should be:

```
> df3
   V1 V2   V3
1:  A  0    0.5
2:  C  0.5  0
3:  D  0    1
4:  B  1    0
```

Can you please help me?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added the `data.table` tag since you are using this package to create your code. Next time do not forget to add tags in order to make your post visible to power users (and not only them) who follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for your examples although it isn't too extensible to more columns.  Does your real world usage use two tables that have the same column names?

```
df3<-merge(df1,df2,"V1")[,list(V2=V2.x/V2.y, V3=V3/V2.y),by=V1]
```

Here's a way that will work with more columns, even if they may or may not have the same name in each table.  This relies on the column to be matched being named `V1` but otherwise it doesn't rely on column names.  It will take whatever the first column after `V1` as the divisor even if there are more than 2 columns in df2.

```
#The first six lines just change column names incase they're the same
oldnames1<-names(df1)[!names(df1) %in% "V1"]
oldnames2<-names(df2)[!names(df2) %in% "V1"]
newnames1<-paste0("x",oldnames1)
newnames2<-paste0("y",oldnames2)
setnames(df1,oldnames1,newnames1)
setnames(df2,oldnames2,newnames2)
df3<-merge(df1,df2,by="V1")
df3[,(oldnames1):=.SD[,!..newnames2]/get(newnames2),by="V1"]
df3[,c(newnames1,newnames2):=NULL]
setnames(df1,newnames1,oldnames1)
setnames(df2,newnames2,oldnames2)
```

Comment: As far as extensibility goes, there's always stuff like `merge(df1,df2,"V1")[,lapply(.SD[,!"V2.y",with=FALSE],\`/\`,V2.y),by=V1]`

Comment: @Frank I did it another way which allows for more columns

Comment: Yes, I see that... there's too much to trawl through for me to judge in what ways that is more general. I suspect your code comment about making a temp column could be addressed with something like `.SD[,!"V2.y",with=FALSE]` but I could be wrong. Also, `.SD/x` coerces to matrix as far as I know.

Comment: @Frank Well the first 6 lines just change the names so that if there are names in common, they aren't anymore so you can pretty much ignore those.

Comment: @Frank I took your advice on how to get rid of the temp column.  I also got rid of reference to `yV1`

Comment: Thanks, I think I can make it work. I indeed have more than 2 columns....48 to be precise...

Comment: @MichaelChirico really scraping the bottom of the barrel looking for things to edit.

Comment: @deanmacgregor it came up in a search :)

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`:

```
setkey(df1, V1)
df1[df2,.(V1,V2=V2/i.V2, V3=V3/i.V2)]
#   V1  V2  V3
#1:  A 0.0 0.5
#2:  B 1.0 0.0
#3:  C 0.5 0.0
#4:  D 0.0 1.0
```

See the comments for more options.

Comment: `df1[df2,.(V2=V2/i.V2, V3=V3/i.V2),by=.EACHI]` or `df1[df2,.(V1, V2=V2/i.V2, V3=V3/i.V2)]`

Comment: No need in `by = .EACHI`, also assignment by reference is preferred, I would go with ```df1[df2, `:=`(V2=V2/i.V2, V3=V3/i.V2)]```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah, but that modifies `df1`, which may not be desired.

Comment: @Frank I read that OP wants to match any value in `df1` with a corrsponding one in `df2` by a key. That sounds just like a left join, so I don't see a reason to create `df3` as all the values in `df1` can be potentially kept if needed.